# WillPopScope should I use return Future.value(true) after Navigator.pop

Tags: flutter

Is using `return Future.value(false);` after `Navigator.pop(context)` is the right way.

If I use 
`Navigator.pop(context, false)`  and after it
`return Future.value(true);`

The application will show black screen after pressing the back button, and no errors in the Logcat.

But if I use the same code without the `Navigator.pop(context)` or without the `return Future.value(true);` everything will be fine, using `return Future.value(false);` also works fine.

*Following a tutorial on Udemy that show `return Future.value(true)` is ok.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found the solution. 
You should use `return Future.value(false);`.
You navigated manually by using `Navigator.pop(context)`, `Future.value(true);` trigger another pop which can't be done because you already exist the page and this crashes the app.

OnWillPop expect a return so By using the `return Future.value(false);` you tell the onWillPop that you handle the closing of the page here.

Comment: this is gold, saved me a huge bug in production line!

Comment: Yeah. This must be the right answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
onWillPop: () {
    Navigator.pop(context, 'ANY RETURN VALUE');
    return new Future(() => false);
  },
```